# Prevent irc bot from getting auto kicked (excess flooding)

Tags: java, irc

I have a bot which analyses chat command and provides a small database. When I tell the bot it should write the content of the database to the irc, it gets kicked because of excess flooding. How can I prevent this?
(I'm using freenode.net)

PS: Here is my code:

```
for (User u : users.values()) {
    ps.println("PRIVMSG " + CHANNEL + " :" + u.toString());
}
```

ps is a PrintStream which writes to Socket.getOutputStream().
CHANNEL is the name of my channel. users.size() is ~ 60.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously a client can't change a servers thresholds for detecting flooding and disconnecting clients which do so. The whole idea of flood protection would be pointless, otherwise.

So, you must limit your output to such a level, that it will not trigger flooding kick. Add a (configurable) sleep between `ps.println` calls, and set the sleep duration so that you don't get kicked.

---

Work-around would be to use a pastebin-like service, and just send URL and summary/title text to IRC in one line. Using these services is a standard procedure for any IRC paste longer than 3 lines these days anyway. Various "pastebin" services have REST APIs ([example](http://pastebin.com/api)), so this should be rather easy way to go.

Comment: Maybe thats the only possible option, but this will extremly slow down my code. But thanks anyway.